# What official videogames implemented the D&D rules as "authentically" as possible?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification

I know there are plenty of videogames that are loosely based on some edition of D&D rules. Are there any official D&D games that tried to replicate it as closely as possible? My question refers to all editions.

Comment: Unfortunately, [list questions are off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/are-list-collection-questions-on-topic) on our site and as such this question is likely to be put on hold.

Comment: Just as a note to readers: kviiri is right to link in our meta on list questions above, but please read it carefully and note well that not every question which can be answered by a list is a "list question" as described in that meta.

Comment: The title and the text differ on an important point: the title asks about *all* such games (which would make this a list question), but the texts asks about existence (giving one example would be proof).

Answer (score 13):

I (with the help of the commenters below!) can think of the following:

- The [*Gold Box*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_Box) series (PC, Commodore, Amiga, Atari ST, NES, Apple II, Macintosh, Sega Genesis) which is built on AD&D rules
- *Baldur's Gate* (PC) which is built on 2e D&D rules
- *Neverwinter Nights* (PC) which is built on 3e D&D rules
- *Temple of Elemental Evil* (PC) which is built on 3.5e D&D rules
- *Dungeons and Dragons Online* (PC) which is built on 3.5e D&D rules
- The *Neverwinter* MMORPG (2013) implements the D&D 4e ruleset, with liberties to accommodate real-time play
- *Sword Coast Legends* (PC) which is built on the 5e D&D rules

---

If you're looking for a more modern RPG that captures the feel of D&D without close adherence to the rules, then I would strongly recommend *Divinity: Original Sin* and its sequel :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84214/discussion-on-answer-by-john-goblin-what-videogames-implemented-the-dd-rules-as).